# Vector multiplication with eigen

Tags: vector, eigen, vector-multiplication

I need to reproduce this Matlab operation:

```
r =  U(:,ii)'*Es
```

Where:
`U` is a matrix (of complex) and`Es` is a vector (of complex)

In the end, what I get is the scalar complex value `r`

Now, I'm trying to do the same with Eigen libs in C++, I've tryied with this:

```
complex<double> r = U.col(jj) * Es;
```

and also

```
complex<double> r = U.col(jj).transpose() * Es;
```

but it nothing works. Can anybody help me? How can I reproduce the same result?
Thank you!

Comment: `U.col(jj).dot(Es)` or `U.col(jj).conj().dot(Es)` (I'm never sure what the convention of Matlab is)

Answer (score 0):

@chtz, thank you. I've tested your suggestions, and the operation required to reproduce the matlab is:

```
U.col(jj).dot(Es)
```

Comment: The following works too: `complex<double> r = U.col(jj).adjoint() * Es;`

Comment: @ggael If `U.col(jj).adjoint() * Es` works, why doesn't `.transpose() * Es` work? (Unless JoJo was using a very old version of Eigen -- I actually did not try his code ...)

Comment: @chtz `.transpose() * Es` compiles and run fine too with pretty old Eigen version, so I guess that JoJo meant to say that the result was incorrect in this case.